# iOS Google App Indexing not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, url-scheme

I am currently working on adding Google App Indexing to iOS app.
(https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/ios/app?utm_campaign=app-indexing-ios-515&utm_source=gdbc&utm_medium=blog)

But it works only on one device - iPhone 4 (iOS 7).
On other devices [GSDDeepLink handleDeepLink:url] do nothing for the same url.

What can be wrong? And what is the difference between iOS 7 and iOS 8 for GSDDeepLink?

Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't forget it's still "Limited Release", not everything is documented well probably. In "Introduction to App Indexing" page there is "Technical requirements" section, and they wrote :

Android:

Developed on apps with a minsdkVersion no higher than 17.
Available on searches using the Google app version 2.8+, and Chrome for Android 4.1+.
Available for signed-in users.

iOS:

Developed using a base SDK of iOS8.  // Answer of your question maybe?
Available on searches using the Google app version 5.3+, and Chrome for iOS.
Available for signed-in users.

That means won't work in iOS7.